# Show by induction: $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}<n$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, induction

Show by induction that for all natural numbers n>3

$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n<n$

Let $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n<n$ be true !

We show that $(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1})<n+1$

$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n(1+\frac{1}{n})<n(1+\frac{1}{n})$

$(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}<n+1$

So now we just need to show that

$(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}<(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}$

So here , If I show that :

$(1+\frac{1}{n+1})<(1+\frac{1}{n})$

Does that mean im done with exercise ?

Comment: Your question title and body do not agree. Do you want $(1/n)^2$ or $1/n$?

Comment: The proof looks fine to me.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews   : $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n<n$

Comment: Don't tell me, edit your question title.

Comment: You forgot to verify the inequality for $n = 3$ (it is true for $n\geq 3$)

Comment: The inductive step is correct, though I found it hard to follow its logics. What about $$(1+\frac1{n+1})^{n+1}<(1+\frac1n)^{n+1}=(1+\frac1n)^n(1+\frac1n)<n(1+\frac1n)=n+1$$

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove for $n=4$ in order that mathematical induction work! To show the desired implication, note that if $n \geq 4$ is such that 
$$
\bigg( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \bigg)^{n} < n,
$$
then
$$
\bigg( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \bigg)^{n+1} = \bigg( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \bigg)^{n} \bigg( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \bigg) < \bigg( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \bigg)^{n}\bigg(1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \bigg) < n + \frac{n}{n+1} < n+1.
$$

Note also that this implication makes no use of the hypothesis that $n \geq 4$, so if you do not check the initial proposition then a wrong conclusion could be drawn!

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we have to prove that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}<n+1$ this is equivalent to $$\frac{\ln(n+2)}{n+2}<\frac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1}$$ this is true for $n>3$ for the proof consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$ with the extremum (maximum) $1/e$ at $x=e$

Comment: Did you read the question? OP came up with an answer, and wanted to know if it was right. If you wanted to offer an alternative approach, start at the top by saying: "An alternate approach." Otherwise, you just seem to be ignoring the OP. (This is also not an inductive approach, really.)

Comment: What do we mean by In and e ?

Comment: $\ln$ means the naturel logarithm to the base $e$ the Euler number